# Litecoin/Bitcoin how divide uint256 target value on difficulty in C++

Tags: c++, math, hex, bitcoin

i'm almost done in implementating litecoin/bitcoin miner in js just for fun, i just don't know ho to find target hex. As docs says, it is max / difficulty, but if difficulty is (for example) 62, how can I perform a division between 0x00000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and 62?

So i get unit256 class from litecoin wallet source, but this class dont have divide operator. So i convert uint256 to double which have implemintation in uint256 class

```
double getdouble() const
{
   double ret = 0.0;
   double fact = 1.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
       ret += fact * pn[i];
       fact *= 4294967296.0;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

But now i need convert this huge double to hex string. This string will be represent target for miner, as far i understand. Or i need this double variable converts back to uint256 and thet get hex from it. Any advise? Thanks!

Comment: You can't go that way. The difficulty doesn't have enough precision to allow you to compute the target. You should only go from target to difficulty. Your work units should include the target.

Comment: ok, so i write miner which use stratum protocol, and stratum dont give me target in hex format, they only give me current difficulty. How i can find target then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So solution is simple:

```
void setdouble(double val)
{
    double ret = val;
    double fact = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        double a = ret / fact;
        pn[i] =  (uint32_t)a;
        fact *= 4294967296.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some context around your solution would've been great. Or links to some docs. What is `WIDTH`? What is `pn`? What is `4294967296.0`?